# How can I convert the 24 hour time format to 12 hour time format?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I can get the 24 hour style time, but how do I get the 12 hour format with the am and pm?

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
```

Comment: With an NSDateFormatter. Do a search on Stack Overflow, there are lots of good examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say, you should use `NSDateFormatter` for your desired format. Hope this will help you.

```
let date = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let time = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

For more information about date formatter see [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter)

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3.1 Answer

```
 let date = Date()                //Jun 1, 2017, 10:22 AM"
 let formatter = DateFormatter()  //<NSDateFormatter: 0x608000244380>
 formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" //<NSDateFormatter: 0x608000244380>
 let time = formatter.string(from: date) //"10:22 AM"
```

Answer (score 3):

Time format must be in 'hh' not HH

```
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   let str=dict["startDateTime"] as! String //if the date is in the array
   let str="16:00" //if you want to use static date
    let index=str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 11)
    let end_index=str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy:-3)
    let dateAsString = str[index ..< end_index]
    let dateFormatter=DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat="HH:mm"

    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: String(dateAsString))
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    let Date12 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    print(Date12)
```