# Date conversion from 24 hours format to 12 hours format in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My iPhone **device's default time format is 24 hours**. I am receiving a date string in the app which is also in 24 hours format. But when I am converting this date string to 12 hours format date string using DateFormatter then it is still returning the 24 hours format.

> I am receiving the date in following format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" and I am converting it to "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" but the time is still in 24 hours format.
>   For e.g. Received date is: 2019-01-08 14:01:04 and converted date is 01/08/2019 14:01.

```
format = MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a
timeZone = Asia/Kolkata (current)
locale = Locale.current
```

here is my code snippet:-

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = format
formatter.timeZone = timeZone
formatter.locale = locale
formatter.string(from: DATE_OBJECT)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert the 24 hour time format to 12 hour time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096533/how-can-i-convert-the-24-hour-time-format-to-12-hour-time-format)

Comment: @Scriptable The answer there is incorrect though. Setting correct locale is the most important thing.

Comment: What does `format` look like?

Comment: @Sulthan might be an idea to post the correct answer there. The question here doesn't actually show the values being set.

Comment: @Scriptable, All those solutions only work if the device default time format is 12 hour. But if the device's default time format in settings is 24 hours then conversion is not happening. you should have read the question carefully before you downvote it and if you downvote at least provide suitable answer.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez format = MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a

Comment: @AnkitSaini actually I never downvoted, although it deserves it. Date/time formatting has been asked and answered many times on here. I have only suggested it *could* be a duplicate, not stated it definitely is. You should do some research before posting, that is why **other** people are downvoting it.

Comment: @Scriptable, Yes I did the research but I did not find the solution in case of device time format is 24 hours. Please let me know if you have any solution or Any link to format time in 12 hours in case if device is set to 24 hours format.

Comment: I am not suggesting any more links after your last reply

Answer (score 1):

I am able to found the solution.

> Set the local of your NSDateFormatter to en_US_POSIX will fix this. It works for both 24-hour and 12 hour format.
>   `Locale.init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Here is the link for detailed information:  http://stephentolton.com/nsdateformatter-24-hour-time-and-region-formats/